# Google Line Charts hAxis sections offset & overlapping Java Dates

Tags: date, google-visualization, overlap, linechart, sections

[Current & Previous Week Google Line Charts to show issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwJAx.png)

Background: This chart is updated programmatically each week and has worked fine for several months. The line chart tracks a percentage of systems in a given state, with the count of systems called out, along with a trend-line over a rolling year.

Issue: This week as shown on the top of linked image (with no changes to the code generating the data or chart), seemingly random sections of of the hAxis date range have moved to the right, overlapping other dates. The trend and annotations on the line itself appear correct.

Any insight or guidance would be very much appreciated!

Code:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" 
      src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={
        'modules':[{
          'name':'visualization',
          'version':'1',
          'packages':['corechart']
        }]
      }"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {

        // Create the data table.
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Date', 'Percent ', {type: 'number', role: 'annotation'}],[new Date(2015, 4, 30), 0.016119402985075, 81],[new Date(2015, 5, 06), 0.018779342723005, 96],[new Date(2015, 5, 13), 0.025033960799534, 129],[new Date(2015, 5, 20), 0.018069973087274, 94],[new Date(2015, 5, 27), 0.017182130584192, 90],[new Date(2015, 6, 04), 0.023132347364429, 122],[new Date(2015, 6, 11), 0.019939804364184, 106],[new Date(2015, 6, 18), 0.017420311341735, 94],[new Date(2015, 6, 25), 0.017922457937089, 98],[new Date(2015, 7, 01), 0.017391304347826, 96],[new Date(2015, 7, 08), 0.020658949243099, 116],[new Date(2015, 7, 15), 0.022210563133963, 127],[new Date(2015, 7, 22), 0.018635664216105, 109],[new Date(2015, 7, 29), 0.017215189873418, 102],[new Date(2015, 8, 05), 0.018827057647451, 113],[new Date(2015, 8, 12), 0.015666226912929, 95],[new Date(2015, 8, 19), 0.013627514600909, 84],[new Date(2015, 8, 26), 0.016435295994894, 103],[new Date(2015, 9, 03), 0.014991320814265, 95],[new Date(2015, 9, 10), 0.013443801782085, 86],[new Date(2015, 9, 17), 0.014195340225274, 92],[new Date(2015, 9, 24), 0.015899709524538, 104],[new Date(2015, 9, 31), 0.01468824940048, 98],[new Date(2015, 10, 07), 0.016303542315103, 110],[new Date(2015, 10, 14), 0.015366603248939, 105],[new Date(2015, 10, 21), 0.017199017199017, 119],[new Date(2015, 10, 28), 0.016353464352317, 114],[new Date(2015, 11, 05), 0.015175152460644, 107],[new Date(2015, 11, 12), 0.017195582273172, 123],[new Date(2015, 11, 19), 0.015932391244112, 115],[new Date(2015, 11, 26), 0.017364939360529, 126],[new Date(2016, 0, 02), 0.012350761630301, 90],[new Date(2016, 0, 09), 0.017178412011362, 127],[new Date(2016, 0, 16), 0.02000266702227, 150],[new Date(2016, 0, 23), 0.017802980350785, 135],[new Date(2016, 0, 30), 0.017995857068876, 139],[new Date(2016, 1, 06), 0.015858805473846, 124],[new Date(2016, 1, 13), 0.018248637688506, 144],[new Date(2016, 1, 20), 0.018827930174564, 151],[new Date(2016, 1, 27), 0.018682276746793, 150],[new Date(2016, 2, 05), 0.01676321952422, 136],[new Date(2016, 2, 12), 0.022989903904634, 189],[new Date(2016, 2, 19), 0.018874729502284, 157],[new Date(2016, 2, 26), 0.018192698982645, 152],[new Date(2016, 3, 02), 0.017251565638662, 146],[new Date(2016, 3, 09), 0.014193548387097, 121],[new Date(2016, 3, 16), 0.012823475046211, 111],[new Date(2016, 3, 23), 0.015923931721847, 139],[new Date(2016, 3, 30), 0.015510019246009, 137],[new Date(2016, 4, 07), 0.014972067039106, 134],[new Date(2016, 4, 14), 0.019345567101481, 175],[new Date(2016, 4, 21), 0.01909150757077, 174],[new Date(2016, 4, 28), 0.018032786885246, 165]        ]);
        // Set chart options
        var options = {
            animation: {startup: 'true', duration: '500'},
            annotations: {'textStyle': {'color': 'black'}, 'style': 'point'},
            chartArea: {right: '20', bottom: '70', left: '70', top: 50, height: '60%', width: '90%'},
            'title':'Rolling Year:  Trend by Week',
            'width':1500,
            'height':400,
            hAxis: {textPosition: 'out', gridlines: {color: 'transparent'}, textStyle: {fontSize: '10'}, slantedText: 'true', ticks: [new Date(2015, 4, 30), new Date(2015, 5, 06), new Date(2015, 5, 13), new Date(2015, 5, 20), new Date(2015, 5, 27), new Date(2015, 6, 04), new Date(2015, 6, 11), new Date(2015, 6, 18), new Date(2015, 6, 25), new Date(2015, 7, 01), new Date(2015, 7, 08), new Date(2015, 7, 15), new Date(2015, 7, 22), new Date(2015, 7, 29), new Date(2015, 8, 05), new Date(2015, 8, 12), new Date(2015, 8, 19), new Date(2015, 8, 26), new Date(2015, 9, 03), new Date(2015, 9, 10), new Date(2015, 9, 17), new Date(2015, 9, 24), new Date(2015, 9, 31), new Date(2015, 10, 07), new Date(2015, 10, 14), new Date(2015, 10, 21), new Date(2015, 10, 28), new Date(2015, 11, 05), new Date(2015, 11, 12), new Date(2015, 11, 19), new Date(2015, 11, 26), new Date(2016, 0, 02), new Date(2016, 0, 09), new Date(2016, 0, 16), new Date(2016, 0, 23), new Date(2016, 0, 30), new Date(2016, 1, 06), new Date(2016, 1, 13), new Date(2016, 1, 20), new Date(2016, 1, 27), new Date(2016, 2, 05), new Date(2016, 2, 12), new Date(2016, 2, 19), new Date(2016, 2, 26), new Date(2016, 3, 02), new Date(2016, 3, 09), new Date(2016, 3, 16), new Date(2016, 3, 23), new Date(2016, 3, 30), new Date(2016, 4, 07), new Date(2016, 4, 14), new Date(2016, 4, 21), new Date(2016, 4, 28)], title: 'Reporting Week', format: 'yyyy-MM-dd'},
            vAxis: {showTextEvery: '1', title: 'Percent & Count ', format: '#,###.#%'},
            legend: {position: 'top'},
            trendlines: { 0: {visibleInLegend: true, pointsVisible: false, title: 'Trend', color: 'red'} }
            };
        // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('DS_Trend'));
        google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {

        console.log(DS_Trend.innerHTML);
        });
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Okay, turns out this was caused by using an outdated library loading methodology. Using the current libraries and loading methodology fixed this.